# Slow execution even with proper indexes defined

Tags: query-performance, execution-plan, mysql-8.0, aws-aurora

I am using AWS Aurora Serverless V2 with MySql. I have a table with 10M rows as shown below.

```
    CREATE TABLE 'VCont' (
  'id' varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  'version' int NOT NULL,
  'colId' bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  'conId' bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  'aId' bigint NOT NULL,
  'oId' bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'startTime' datetime NOT NULL,
  'endTime' datetime NOT NULL,
  'trType' varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  'cc' varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  'price' int DEFAULT NULL,
  'starRating' varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  'isAdult' char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  'statId' int DEFAULT NULL,
  'parId' int DEFAULT NULL,
  'vLocal' varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  'createDate' datetime NOT NULL,
  'deviceType' varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  'conSupPId' int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  'brandingparId' int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  'categories' varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  'collectionType' varchar(128) DEFAULT '-1',
  'duration' int NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  'linearStartTime' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'isAvailableTimeLocal' tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  'ccCreateDateTime' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  'ccUpdateDateTime' datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  UNIQUE KEY 'uidx_ct_as_of_vl_tt_dt' ('conId','aId','oId','vLocal','trType','deviceType'),
  KEY 'idx_ct_pt_vl' ('conId','parId','vLocal'),
  KEY 'idx_cl_pt' ('colId','parId'),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The below query uses the right index, but the execution takes over 2 seconds.

```
SELECT 
        conSupPId, statId, trType, vLocal, brandingparId
    FROM
        VCont
    WHERE
        parId IN (4576, 1005006, 1006190, 1006173, 4547, 4808, 1006246, 4809, 1006004, 1009011, 1005040, 3455)
        AND colId = 65273433;
```

I have enabled profiling and observed that it spent over 2 seconds in the 'executing' phase. Verified the plan to make sure it is using the right index:

```
-> Index range scan on VCont using idx_cl_pt, with index condition: ((VCont.colId = 16642) and (VCont.parId in (4576,1005006,1006190,1006173,4547,4808,1006246,4809,1006004,1009011,1005040,3455)))  (cost=3163.19 rows=4585) (actual time=10.036..1984.627 rows=4576 loops=1)
```

Do you see any issue in the way I define the indexes here? Any thoughts on how to tune this query?

Thanks for checking!